# Django page failing to render - error in views.py url path

Tags: python, django, url, view

I have an error arising in the views.py file, and as a result I cannot load the page.

**music/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Album

# Create your views here.

#each URL is connected to a view or an Http Response

def index(request):
    all_albums = Album.objects.all()
    html = ' '
    for album in all_albums:
        url= '/music/' + str(album_id) + '/'
        html +='<a href="' + url + '">'+album.album_title+'</a><br>'
    return HttpResponse(html)

def detail(request,album_id):
    return HttpResponse("<h2>Details for Album id:" + str(album_id) + "</h2>")
```

**The line causing the error is presumably:**

```
url= '/music/' + str(album_id) + '/'
```

**The actual (page) error is:**

```
NameError at /music/
name 'album_id' is not defined
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/
Django Version: 2.0
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
name 'album_id' is not defined
Exception Location: C:\Users\User\Desktop\website\music\views.py in index, line 13
Python Executable:  C:\Python34\python.exe
Python Version: 3.4.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\website',
```

In a separate test album_id does seem to be "accessbile" in that

http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/1/

will correctly load the page (the album id number is displayed on the page).

The error points to the code above, but I cannot see how to fix it. Following the New Boston Tutorials and I have googled to see if there is a Django 2.0 fix to no avail

To summarise:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/ is what doesn't work.

http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/1 or http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/3 displays fine with the album id being generated.

**UPDATE**

**Also posting urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

from . import views #the dot means look at the current directory - look for a module called views

urlpatterns = [
    #this is matching /music/
     path('', views.index, name='index'),
     path("<album_id>/", views.detail, name="detail")
```

]

Comment: Can you post your urls.py code so we can see how the urlpatterns is set up

Comment: see update. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
def index(request):
    all_albums = Album.objects.all()
    html = ' '
    for album in all_albums:
        url= '/music/' + str(album_id) + '/'
```

You haven’t defined `album_id` before you use it.

You are in the loop `for album in all_albums:`, so if you want the album id, use `album.id`.

You wouldn’t normally built the string in the view like that. Hopefully your tutorial will move on to rendering templates later.

Comment: I have this for the render but cannot move forward due to some sort of indentation error - but I can't see what!

Comment: Please don’t post code in the comments. It’s difficult to read and impossible to see the indentation. If you have indentation errors, make sure your code only includes spaces and does not have any tabs. Similar to my comment before, you wouldn’t write code like that in practice, you would use the `render` shortcut instead.